# Unable to pipe output after grep

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I'm filtering an Apache log, but concatenating multiple filters I got no output. Trying to reduce the issue to a minimal example it seems that grep is unable to forward the output to the pipe

```
$ tail -F access_log | grep test
10.108.57.6 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:35:55 +0000] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 202 "-" "curl/7.11.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.11.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2d ipv6 zlib/1.1.3" 161

$ tail -F access_log | grep test | grep test
# nothing

$ tail -F access_log | grep test | sed 's/test/asd/g'
# nothing

$  tail -F access_log | sed 's/test/asd/g' | grep asd
10.108.57.6 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:44:58 +0000] "GET /asd HTTP/1.1" 404 202 "-" "curl/7.11.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.11.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2d ipv6 zlib/1.1.3" 143
```

Any light?

I'm on a *Centos 7.2*, with *grep 2.20*

Comment: are you positive that there is a request matching your `| grep test | grep test` example when you issue it? the problem is that your data is different each time you run the commands. i recommend creating a static file with some requests you know you want to filter and manipulate and cat them through your pipes

Comment: of course, the issue was reproduced repeating the request on the same _test_ page, as seen in the first example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For grepping stream (`tail -f`)
it's almost always better to use `grep --line-buffered` instead of just `grep`

From official docs:

> --line-buffered Use line buffering on output. This can cause a performance penalty.

*In other words:* Write output each time when grep get input and do not wait for filling grep buffer

Comment: sed also buffer lines, so if your lines are short use -u option